# Incluir dados no Json além do que vem via Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, api, ionic

Estou construindo uma API em PHP/Mysql que vai alimentar um APP hibrido, também em construção, via Ionic. O transito de dados é via Json.

Adianto que sou novato no Ionic, Angular, JS, e Json... Razoavel em PHP e Mysql. Ou seja... heeeeelllllllp please!!!

Na pratica eu faço um select:

```
$sql = "select id, titulo, ano from tabela WHERE titulo!='' ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 10";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
```

Crio um array

```
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
```

Encodo

```
echo json_encode($emparray), "\n";
```

Fecho a conecção

```
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Funciona!!! Cada item é encodado corretamente e o Ionic interpreta ok (relativamente ok... as formatações html, quebra de linha etc não são interpretadas no app, mas é questão pra outra pergunta.).

O que eu preciso então?

Quero incluir dados além do que vem 'do select', encodar e enviar pro Ionic.

Ex.: Colocar a variavel

```
$site=www.com.br;
$autor=Pedro;
```

E elas, ainda que não venham do Mysql, seja adicionadas no Json.

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente você pode fazer assim:

```
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}

$emparray['site'] = 'www.com.br';
$emparray['autor'] = 'Pedro';

echo json_encode($emparray), "\n";
```

Lembre-se que antes de virar um json ele é simplesmente um Array PHP, você pode manipulá-lo da maneira como bem entender e depois encodar como JSON que ele vai ser transposto normalmente.

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Ocorre que não funcionou plenamente, me desculpe, devido a um detalhe não mencionado na pergunta, o seguinte:

Um item $emparray[] é dinamico (mas personalizado), vindo do BD. Eu coloquei dentro do while{} e até puxa certo mas apenas uma vez, não fica num looping (no caso 10 itens / limit 10).